# When I delete value from array, it messes up printf as it hs a empty space with delimeters

Tags: bash

The script below gets you to write a bunch of vlans into a array, and then I want to use this to remove another piece of config with regards to a line stated "dhcp snooping"

```
$ cat nm
#!/bin/bash

echo "enter old vlans"
while read line
do
    oldvlans=("${oldvlans[@]}" $line)
done

delete=790
for del in ${delete[@]}
do
    oldvlans=("${oldvlans[@]/$del}")
done
    printf -v joinedoldvlans '%s,' "${oldvlans[@]}"
    echo "no ip dhcp snooping vlan ${joinedoldvlans%,}"

$ ./nm
enter old vlans
119
790
999
no ip dhcp snooping vlan 119,,999
```

The problem I have is the formatting now. I wanted the output on the last line to look like this:

```
no ip dhcp snooping vlan 119,999
```

But I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `oldvlans=("${oldvlans[@]/$del}")` doesn't actually remove any elements from the array, it just removes the given string from the existing elements. Also, it'd match the given string from the middle of an element too, e.g. having `del=790`, would turn `1790` into just `1`.

I don't think there's a better way to filter values out of the array other than building a new one:

```
a=(111 222 333)
b=()
for x in "${a[@]}"; do
    if [[ "$x" != 222 ]]; then
        b+=("$x")
    fi
done
printf "<%s> " "${b[@]}"; echo
# prints <111> <333>
```

Of course, if you have a list of values you want to remove, you'd at least need a test to see if a certain element exists in the array, and that's also not simple in Bash.

You could perhaps use a sparse array instead, with the active data in the *keys/indexes*:

```
declare -a vlans=()

# fill the array (from a string here)
while read v; do
    vlans+=(["$v"]=1)
done <<< $'111\n790\n1790\n'

# remove these two
for r in 790 999; do
    unset "vlans[$r]"
done
printf "<%s> " "${!vlans[@]}"; echo
# prints <1790> <111>
```

(You could also use an associative array, but the keys would come out in an undetermined order.)

Doing stuff like this is something that might be better done in some other programming language, IMO.